# find string in dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, select

How do I find columns with observations containing a specified string? I have a very large data frame in which multiple variables do not contain any information (i.e. "confidential"). I want to select all columns that contain "**CONFIDENTIAL**" anywhere.

The data frame looks like the one below.

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1:6),
    name = c("**CONFIDENTIAL**"),
    location = c("**CONFIDENTIAL**"), 
    profession = c("farmer", "magician", "butcher", "farmer", "postman", "teacher"))

df
```

I'd like the output to be either the `colnames` (i.e., "name", "location") or look like when using `select` so I can remove the columns from the data frame:

```
select(df, -c(name, location))
```

I tried the below but that shows me all locations of **CONFIDENTIAL** rather than just the columns.

```
which(df == "**CONFIDENTIAL**", arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `where`:

```r
df %>% 
  select(where(~ any(.x == "**CONFIDENTIAL**")))
```

Or with `!` if you want to exclude them:

```r
df %>% 
  select(!where(~ any(.x == "**CONFIDENTIAL**")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While this works with the example I provided it doesn't work with the dataset I am using (it's World Bank LSMS-ISA data) because not all confidential variables are character variables but some are double.

I get the following error: 

Error in `vec_equal()`:
! Can't combine `..1` <character> and `..2` <double>.

 What would be a good work around that?

Comment: Can you add an example of that in your question?

Answer (score 1):

With `base`:

Using colSums:

```r
df[, colSums(df == "**CONFIDENTIAL**") == 0]
```

Using your attempted approach:

```r
df[, -which(df == "**CONFIDENTIAL**", arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]]
```

Output:

```
  id profession
1  1     farmer
2  2   magician
3  3    butcher
4  4     farmer
5  5    postman
6  6    teacher
```